# Instafeed.js - Instagram script CSS Styling Not Applying To Elemements

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

Added instafeed.js to my website and successfully styled it. It is a feed to show instagram photos on a website. This worked correctly.

This is what I am trying to do: Now trying to add a roll over feature which highlights each icon...

Added css, then changed script and it won't respond as it is supposed to.

Debugged and no errors....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var userFeed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'user',
        userId: 1481598384,
        accessToken: '1481598384.467ede5.3870e3db231943d98eb5c12bc04b1463',
      limit: 10,  
      after: function () {
    var images = $("#instafeed").find('a');
    $.each(images, function(index, image) {
      var delay = (index * 75) + 'ms';
      $(image).css('-webkit-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('-moz-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('-ms-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('-o-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).addClass('animated flipInX');
    });
  },
    });
    userFeed.run();
</script> 


    <center> 
        <div id="instafeed">

          <a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /><div class="likes">&hearts; {{likes}}</div></a>


        </div> 
    </center>
```

This is the CSS:

```
#instafeed a {
  padding:5px 5px 1px 5px;
  margin:10px;
  border:1px solid #e1e1e1;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position:relative;
}

#instafeed .likes {
  background:rgba(10,100,105,0.8);
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:1em;
  position:absolute;
  color:#fff;
  right:5px;
  top:5px;
  left:5px;
  opacity:0;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:150px;
  text-shadow:0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 100ms ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 100ms ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 100ms ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity 100ms ease;
    transition: opacity 100ms ease;
}

#instafeed a:hover .likes {
  opacity:1;
}
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/timsalabim/u7yc810v/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the `template` that `instafeed.js` should render. Currently it is removing your original markup: http://instafeedjs.com/

**HTML**

```
<div id="instafeed"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var userFeed = new Instafeed({
  get: 'user',
  userId: 1481598384,
  accessToken: '1481598384.467ede5.3870e3db231943d98eb5c12bc04b1463',
  limit: 10,  
  template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /><div class="likes">&hearts; {{likes}}</div></a>',
  after: function () {
    var images = $("#instafeed").find('a');
    $.each(images, function(index, image) {
      var delay = (index * 75) + 'ms';
      $(image).css('-webkit-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('-moz-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('-ms-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('-o-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).addClass('animated flipInX');
    });
  },
});

userFeed.run();
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ocnf0z8e/

Comment: The fiddle is working however something is conflicting on the live site and the images do not display. Debug shows nothing

Comment: particle-cinnamon.myshopify.com  temp password zaccy86-

Comment: The code needs to follow the answer. Make sure the HTML / JS is the same and in the same order. :D

Comment: Switched around the HTML with the JS... Could this be an issue with Shopifys liquid files which places sections from different files?

Comment: Password changed? And no, its not a Shopify issue. Liquid includes the snippets where you tell it to.

Comment: Same password. Have it working without the rollover section of the script which you should be able to see but as soon as I try to make it work like the fiddle it does not display images at all...

Comment: You need to include the javascript from this answer. At the moment the site shows the javascript from your question, which is missing the template object.

Comment: I changed it back last night when playing with it... Returned it to your fiddle script and with the issue